# Subclassing template class and connect to signal

Tags: c++, qt, templates

I'm trying to subclass `QQueue` in order to add some functionality.
Actually, I wasn't able to subclass but because the code is very short I rewrote my own implementation:

```
#ifndef MYQUEUE_H
#define MYQUEUE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtCore/qlist.h>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

template <class T>
class MyQueue : public QList<T>
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    // compiler-generated special member functions are fine!
    inline void swap(MyQueue<T> &other) Q_DECL_NOTHROW { QList<T>::swap(other); } // prevent QList<->QQueue swaps
#ifndef Q_QDOC
    // bring in QList::swap(int, int). We cannot say using QList<T>::swap,
    // because we don't want to make swap(QList&) available.
    inline void swap(int i, int j) { QList<T>::swap(i, j); }
#endif
    inline void enqueue(const T &t) { QList<T>::append(t); emit enqueued(); }
    inline T dequeue() { return QList<T>::takeFirst(); }
    inline T &head() { return QList<T>::first(); }
    inline const T &head() const { return QList<T>::first(); }

signals:
    void enqueued();
};

QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // MYQUEUE_H
```

Basically, it emits a signal whenever something is enqueued.
I don't know the correct syntax to bind that signal to a slot:

```
MyQueue<QString> queue;
connect(&queue, &MyQueue::enqueued, this, &MainWindow::process_queue);
```

> error: 'template class MyQueue' used without template parameters
>     connect(&queue, &MyQueue::enqueued, this, &MainWindow::process_queue);
>                        ^

It says that I'm using `MyQueue` (that is a template class) without specifying the template parameters (`QString`).

I tried to add it but I did in a wrong way:

```
connect(&queue, &MyQueue<QString>::enqueued, this, &MainWindow::process_queue);
```

> error: no matching function for call to 'MainWindow::connect(MyQueue*, void (MyQueue::*)(), MainWindow*, void (MainWindow::*)())'

What's the right syntax to connect such a signal?

Comment: I don't think your approach will work. Apart from template class, if you want to use signals/slots you have to use them with `QObject`s, or its subclasses.

Comment: Why can't `MyQueue` inherit from a non-template base class and put the required `signal` in the base class?

Comment: Do you mean a sort of wrapper that adds the required signals? It could be an acceptable workaround.

Answer (score 2):

[qt](/questions/tagged/qt) uses moc for their signal and slot connections; which does not support templates. If you're interested in rationale you can read more about this decision here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/why-moc.html

That said, all the functionality that you've shown in your example is availible in a [`QStringList`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html) so you may consider it as an option in this instance.

Comment: What a pity! `QString` is just an example, I have a queue of a custom type. I would like to be notified when the queue is changed (enqueued, dequed, etc...)

Comment: @Mark Instead of connecting the signal to the `MyQueue` could you connect it to the points where it is enqueued and dequeued? That seems the more customary way to go about this.

Comment: Because this might happen in several parts of the code, I would avoid to repeat the same snippet here and there.

Comment: @Mark I think the options that you have within the framework Qt has provided I'm seeing 3 options, listed from best to worst: 1) Add signals from all the enquing and dequing locations 2) Use a non-templatized container 3) Create a non-templatized interface which could be used to signal with.

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment... you could probably have `MyQueue` inherit from a suitable base class that has the required signals.

```
class MyQueueBase: public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT;
public:
  virtual ~MyQueueBase ()
    {}
signals:
  void enqueued();
};
```

Then `MyQueue` becomes...

```
template<class T>
class MyQueue: public MyQueueBase,
               public QList<T>
{
public:

  /*
   * All as before but without the signal declaration.
   */
};
```

Code using the above can connect either to the base class or the derived class...

```
connect(&queue, &MyQueueBase::enqueued, this, &MainWindow::process_queue);
connect(&queue, &MyQueue<QString>::enqueued, this, &MainWindow::process_queue);
```

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of this solution because of the extra work required, and the added layer of indirection/maintenance. But if I'm honest I have used this solution before when other workarounds were more odious. So I'm begrudgingly giving this a +1, cause even though it's a last resort, it is the best solution in some cases.